# images and absolute position DIV

Tags: css

I would like to ask one question about css positioning and image

I have one outerwrapper div I set it's margin equal from the body element.

My problem is when I place an image in this outerwrapper container it overflow which I don't want.

I want to stay image in its outerwrapper div container. It's css here.

```
 #outerwrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
  border: solid 2px green;
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-right:30px;
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  width: calc(100% - 60px);

}
```

Here is working jsfiddle code.

https://jsfiddle.net/magtechpro/s3r2cf8r/3/

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the css class for `.img-responsive`

```
.img-responsive {max-width:100%;height:auto}
```

This will maintain the images proportions. You can also add `overflow:hidden` to your `#outerwrapper`.

If you don't care so much about keeping the proportion of the image intact but just want it to cover the area use this instead:

```
.img-responsive {width:100%;height:100%;}
```

Comment: Just to help future proof your code, in case you add another image in your project where you've added in height and width attributes, but also used the img-responsive class. But for this example alone - it's not needed.

Comment: Bootstraps "img-responsive" class also includes "display: block;"

Comment: Thanks for you answer. When you do overflow hidden. Image does not show 100% in height. it cuts off if you notice. Image should display 100% in this container.

Comment: @RanaHussain If that's the case and you don't want the image to maintain it's proportions, change the css inside .img-responsive to  .img-responsive {width:100%;height:100%;}

Comment: Thanks guys, however I want to image maintain it's proportions, Here is the example site. I want similar layout.

http://nicolas-bussiere.fr/

Comment: remove the image altogether and add it as a background image to your #outerwrapper. background: url(http://lorempixel.com/city/1160/1390) center center/cover no-repeat ;

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow: hidden` to your `#outerwrapper`

https://jsfiddle.net/nt2n9xu6/

Comment: Thanks for you answer. When you do overflow hidden. Image does not show 100% in height. it cuts off if you notice.

Comment: Thanks this trick worked, However when you shrink the window image width start to cut off how do i deal with this in responsive way. Thanks